# Android base64 encoding image not compatible with PHP base64 decoding

Tags: java, php, android, image-processing, base64

There are lots of questions similar to this on stackoverflow, but I am yet to find one that solves my issue. So I'm asking a new question.

My issue is that the base64 encoding of an image in android does not appear to give a string that can be decoded in PHP.

In android I get a bitmap from the camera or gallery:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
  }
}
```

Then I encode the bitmap to a string:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I've been pulling the string out at this point in debug mode and putting it into a php function:

```
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg;');
echo base64_decode($imageString); //Image string is the value pulled out of the debugger
```

Originally I had the android script doing a POST request directly but it makes no difference so this is as simple as I can make the process. I've tried using different base64 flags such as NO_WRAP but it doesn't make any difference. Online base64 image decoders also do not work with the strings produced from android.

What am I missing?

**Update**: My test where I was copying the string out of debug and manually putting it through PHP was a bit of a red herring. That should have worked but I think the length of the strings caused a problem. The actual issue I was having appeared to be that when I was preparing the post request the base64 string was changing, the `+` where becoming spaces. I think this happened as I am converting `map` of properties to a `jsonObject` which is then output as a string to the body of the request. I don't want to change my request manager so now I am doing this:

- Encoding the image with `Base64.URL_SAFE`
- In PHP using `str_replace` to change the `-` to `+` and the `_` to `/`.

This appears to be working now, although the `str_replace`s seem a little clunky.

Comment: The issue is due to encoding. Php's echo function (from memory) writes text data, but cannot handle binary data.

Comment: I should have probably added that I originally was outputting to a file, this was just a test. But I don't think the echo is the problem, it works fine if I use a sample base64 string. My problem appears to be the base64 string that I get from android, PHP just doesn't like it.

Comment: Try encoding a smaller test (a sentence for example) and see if that matches the reference output from android.

Comment: I've tried doing a sentence and it appears the same, its harder to test with an image as its complicated to get the bitmap onto a ByteArrayOutputStream without compression. But my test appeared to show different outputs.